# How can I avoid optional chaining in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to store object data called `Targetfarms` in redux. I assigned a type called `Farmstype` to `Targetfarms`.

However, when I bring `Targetfarms` with `useSelector` in the `MainPage` component and I want to use `targetfarm.aircon`, if I do not use optional chaining in `Targetfarms`, this error occurs.

```
Targetfarms is possibly null,
```

If I use optional chaining, I can get `Targetfarms` data normally, but I don't want to use optional chaining as much as possible.

How can I fix my code?

This is my code:

```
export interface Farmstype {
    aircon: aircontype;
    children: Farmstype[];
    equips: euiptype[];
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
    modDate: string;
    name: string;
    placeId: number;
    placeInfo: placeInfotype;
    productCode: string;
    productCodeInfo: productCodeInfotypes;
    productLifeCycles: productLifeCyclestype[];
    roadNameAddress: string;
    stnIds: number;
    type: string;
}

interface InitialState {
    Targetfarms: Farmstype | null;
}

const initialState: InitialState = {
    Targetfarms: null,
};



const postSlice = createSlice({
    name: "post",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        // targetLoadFarm
        targetFarm(state, action: PayloadAction<Farmstype>) {
            state.Targetfarms = action.payload;
        },
    }
```

MainPage

```
const MainPage = () => {
    const { Targetfarms} = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.post);

    console.log("Targetfarms:", Targetfarms?.placeId);    // Targetfarms is possibly null,

}
```

Comment: _"how can i fix my code?"_ - Read/Understand what optional chaining does/solves for you and then re-do that behavior on your own.

Comment: "but I don't want to use optional chaining as much as possible" - Why not? It's so useful.

Comment: @DrewReese because i have to use so many time Targetfarms.property ...

Comment: Make `Targetfarms` non-nullable and make all the properties optional. But this really just pushes the issue downstream. Nullable values sometimes can't be avoided, and the Optional Chaining operator is great for this. The alternative is a truthy if-check/block prior to accessing into objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea to get rid of optional chaining with you current setup would be to statically type the state of the world and write different components.

Not sure I structured your store correctly but you get the idea.

```js
type RootState = {
    app: 'init' | 'running' // we model the state of the app
    post: {
       Targetfarms: Farmstype | null
    }
}

// We dispatch to the correct implementation depending on the state of the world
const MainPage = () =>
    useSelector({ app }: RootState) => app) === 'running'
        ? RunningPage()
        : InitPage();

const RunningPage = () => {
    const { Targetfarms } = useSelector((state: RunningState) => state.post);

    // OK
    const f = Targetfarms.placeId

}

const InitPage = () => {
    const { Targetfarms } = useSelector((state: InitState) => state.post);

    // @ts-expect-error: Targetfarms is possibly null
    const f = Targetfarms.placeId

}
```

There are many ways to produce the different states. This is an option.

```js
// When the app is 'running' `post/Targetfarms` is unlocked
type RunningState = Unlock<RootState, ['post', 'Targetfarms']> & {
   state: 'running'
};

// Otherwise Targetfarms is still nullable
type InitState = RootState & {
   state: 'init'
};

type Unlock<State, Path extends PropertyKey[]> = unknown & {
    [K in keyof State]: K extends Path[0]
        ? Path['length'] extends 1
            ? NonNullable<State[K]>
            : Unlock<
                State[K],
                Path extends [PropertyKey, ...infer U] ? U & PropertyKey[] : never
            >
        : State[K]
}
```

This solution can start to become interesting if you have few `app` states and lots of nullable pieces of state. Basically you take the decision of what state the app is in once at the root instead of many times where the values are needed.

Comment: it would be very helpful if you can also explain the Unlock type here in more detail. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry that it is so confusing. It is actually very sloppy, I will replace it with something else and I don't recommend using it as is. For the record it maps every field of its first input recursively until the end of the path is reached, then it checks whether the current field name matches the last path item, and if it does it makes the value non-nullable. Fields which are shallower that the length of the path are ignored. The intersection with `unknown` is just here for pretty printing. The main problem with this type is that it looks like it's walking the path but it doesn't.

Comment: In my edit I swapped the check for `Path['length']` and the check for `Path[0]`, which restricts the changes to properties along the path.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is `Unlock` a typescript utility?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this. It's user defined. There is a short list of built-in utility types which you can find in the TS handbook. Most of them you can implement yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that you are trying to access a property of an object that may be null or undefined before the initialization. To avoid this error, you have a few options:

You can check if the object is null or undefined before trying to access its properties. For example:

```
if (Targetfarms) {
  console.log(Targetfarms.placeId);
}
```

You can set a default value for Targetfarms using the || operator. For example:

```
const {Targetfarms} = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.post) || {};
console.log(Targetfarms.placeId);
```

This will set the default value of Targetfarms to an empty object, which means you can access its properties without getting an error.

Note: I think and it's only my opinion here, optional chaining it's a good approach to avoid null or undefined.

Comment: i used your code but error says "Property placeId does not exist on type {}"

Comment: did you add the curly braces to Targetfarms 
const { Targetfarms } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.post.Targetfarms) || {};

Comment: The default value option is a very bad advice. The point of TS is to force you to handle the possibility of `state.Targetfarms` being `null`. If you replace it with a degenerate object you turn off type checking and even runtime errors but you still get bugs

Comment: @AbodiAtrash i did both

Comment: `{}` is an empty object. It has no properties. If you want to shoot yourself in the foot you must write `{} as Farmstype`